# Erlang shell - no input for commands

Tags: erlang, archlinux, erlang-shell

My os: arch linux. I recently installed erlang (Erlang (BEAM) emulator version 9.0.1).

When I type "erl" command I expect the erlang shell to start invoking the commands I type (for the simplest example: 2+3. should return 5)

However, after I run "erl" nothing shows up on screen. I can type anything I want, nothing is executed. Images with example are attached.

[What I expect.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2f8cS.png)

[What I got.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwRiF.jpg)

Now I only started to learn erlang, and this is confusing. Don't know if it is some repository bug, or erlang normal behavior?

UPD: I got some custom configuration in .bashrc file:

```
# setup color variables
color_is_on=
color_red=
color_green=
color_yellow=
color_blue=
color_white=
color_gray=
color_bg_red=
color_off=
color_user=
if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    color_is_on=true
    color_black="\[$(/usr/bin/tput setaf 0)\]"
    color_red="\[$(/usr/bin/tput setaf 1)\]"
    color_green="\[$(/usr/bin/tput setaf 2)\]"
    color_yellow="\[$(/usr/bin/tput setaf 3)\]"
    color_blue="\[$(/usr/bin/tput setaf 6)\]"
    color_white="\[$(/usr/bin/tput setaf 7)\]"
    color_gray="\[$(/usr/bin/tput setaf 8)\]"
    color_off="\[$(/usr/bin/tput sgr0)\]"

    color_error="$(/usr/bin/tput setab 1)$(/usr/bin/tput setaf 7)"
    color_error_off="$(/usr/bin/tput sgr0)"

    # set user color
    case `id -u` in
        0) color_user=$color_red ;;
        *) color_user=$color_green ;;
    esac
fi



function prompt_command {
    # get cursor position and add new line if we're not in first column
    exec < /dev/tty
    local OLDSTTY=$(stty -g)
    stty raw -echo min 0
    echo -en "\033[6n" > /dev/tty && read -sdR CURPOS
    stty $OLDSTTY
    [[ ${CURPOS##*;} -gt 1 ]] && echo "${color_error}↵${color_error_off}"


    # build b/w prompt for git and vertial env
    [[ ! -z $GIT_BRANCH ]] && PS1_GIT=" (git: ${GIT_BRANCH})"
    [[ ! -z $VIRTUAL_ENV ]] && PS1_VENV=" (venv: ${VIRTUAL_ENV#$WORKON_HOME})"

    # calculate fillsize
    local fillsize=$(($COLUMNS-$(printf "${USER}@${HOSTNAME}:${PWD}:${PWDNAME}${PS1_GIT}${PS1_VENV} " | wc -c | tr -d " ")))

    local FILL=$color_white
    while [ $fillsize -gt 0 ]; do FILL="${FILL}─"; fillsize=$(($fillsize-1)); done
    FILL="${FILL}${color_off}"



    # set new color prompt
    PS1="${color_user}${USER}${color_off}@${color_yellow}${HOSTNAME}${color_off}:${color_white}${PWD}:${PWDNAME}${color_off}${PS1_GIT}${PS1_VENV} ${FILL}\n➜ "
}


PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_command
```

After removing this configuration, erl started to work normally.

Comment: You don't get a prompt `1>`?

Comment: Yes, exactly, no prompt 1>

Comment: And how exactly did you install erlang?

Comment: From arch repository, pacman -S erlang (/erlang-nox, erlang19-nox, I tried a few)

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Try to compile from source, maybe?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Created a clean vagrant archlinux box. `uname -r` gives `4.11.9-1-ARCH`. Next, a `pacman -S erlang` gives me a clean erlang install with a working shell.

Comment: Do a `awk '/pacman -S erlang/{f=1} f{print; if (/transaction completed/) f=0}' /var/log/pacman.log` and check if all dependencies are installed.

Comment: You won't believe that, I just installed erlang for Fedora (from repository) on completely different computer and have the same problem. 
I'll look at the dependencies when I'll be at home and will try to build it from source. But this is very, very strange.
I have same .bashrc config and urxvt installed on both computers. Maybe they are the reason. (Though, it works the same in gnome-terminal)

Comment: I found the reason. I had some .bashrc configuration for different colors in console, which, being removed, leaded to the normal work of erl.

Comment: Well done. Nobody could answer this one, but yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the help, anyway.

Comment: NP. I'll check your .bashrc and put that in an answer.